# How to record audit logs for only one specified file in FreeBSD?

Tags: logging, freebsd, audit, auditd

On Red Hat Linux I can specify the file I want to record audit logs for with this command:

```
auditctl -a exit,always -F path=/tmp/foo.txt -F perm=war
```

I cannot figure out how to do a similar thing on FreeBSD. The only way I've found to record audit logs for files is to add [the `fr` flag to my `/etc/security/audit_control` file](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/audit-config.html#event-selection).

Unfortunately, this way doesn't allow me to specify the file.

---

#### Update 1:

I asked about it on the *trustedbsd-discuss* mailing list. You can view [the email here](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/trustedbsd-discuss/2016-May/000927.html). I did not receive any answer yet.

Comment: Maybe you could try on one of the mailing lists https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/eresources-mail.html or the FreeBSD forum https://forums.freebsd.org/ People seem to be much more active there than on SF